# Uniform Distribution of Points on a Surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: probability, differential-geometry, surfaces

Let $\phi : U \subset \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be an embedding of a $k$-dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is there a general prescription for selecting points $p$ in $U$ such that the points $\phi(p)$ will be uniformly distributed in $\phi(U)$?

I first thought about this in the context of uniformly distributing points on the sphere. One has the standard parametrization $\phi : (0,1) \times (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}^3$ where 
$$\phi(u,v) = (\cos(2\pi u) \sin(\pi v), \sin (2\pi u) \sin (\pi v) , \cos(\pi v))
$$
Uniformly selected points from $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ get mapped to non-uniformly distributed points on the sphere by $\phi$. It seems like instead we have to select points $(x,y)$ uniformly from $(0,1) \times (0,1)$, then map them to points $(u,v) = \psi(x,y) \equiv \left(x, \frac{1}{\pi}\cos^{-1}(2y - 1)\right)$, and then finally use $\phi$ to map those points to the sphere in order to get uniformly distributed points on the sphere.

I'm looking to generalize this treatment of the sphere to embedded $k$-surfaces. That is, how do we select a map $\psi : U \to U$ such that $\phi \circ \psi : U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ takes points uniformly distributed on $U$ to points uniformly distributed on the $k$-dimensional surface $(\phi \circ \psi)(U)$?

Comment: Could you maybe provide more rigour about how is a uniform distribution on a manifold is defined? I would guess it means something like $P(X\in N) = \frac{\int_N d\sigma}{\int_M d\sigma}$ for $N\subseteq M$?

Comment: That seems like a reasonable definition to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find the following ovservation. Let us denote $\rho = \phi \circ \psi$. We want to find $\psi$ such that for all open subsets $W \subseteq U$, the submanifold $\rho(W)$ satisfies that $\rho$ preserves the probabiliy:

$$\frac{\int_W \sqrt{\det (D\rho ^T D\rho)}\text{d}u}{\text{vol}_k(M)}=\frac{\int_W \text{d}u}{\text{vol}_k(U)}$$

Since this is for all $W$ we must have
$$\frac{\sqrt{\det (D\rho ^T D\rho)}}{\text{vol}_k(M)}=\frac{1}{\text{vol}_k(U)}$$
Note that by the chain rule
$$\sqrt{\det (D\rho ^T D\rho)}=\sqrt{\det ((D\phi \circ \psi D\psi)^T(D\phi \circ \psi D\psi)}=\sqrt{\det (D\psi^T (D\phi \circ \psi)^T (D\phi \circ \psi) D\psi}$$ $$=|\det D\psi|\sqrt{\det ((D\phi \circ \psi)^T (D\phi \circ \psi)}=\frac{\text{vol}_k(M)}{\text{vol}_k(U)}$$
From here I think it's pretty obvious that generally you can't solve explicitly for $\psi$, At least that's my guess.

Comment: Makes sense. Does make me wonder how it's implemented in practice, though. Maybe there isn't much need to distribute points uniformly over a surface in full generality?